# prove $G=HN$, if $N \lhd G$ with prime index, and $H$ is not contained in $N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with the following properties

- G has a normal subgroup $N$ with $[G;N]=p$ where $p$ is a prime number;
- G has a subgroup $H$ such that $H$ is not contained in $N$

Prove

$$G=HN$$

---

attempt1

$\frac{|G|}{|N|} =p$ is a quotient group so $n=p|N|$

**Theorem 8.7** hungerford $p$ is prime every group of order $p$ is cylcic and isomorphic to $Z_p$

call that $<g_p> =\frac{G}{N} \cong Z_p$

$$\frac{G}{N}=\{g_p, \dots , g_p^p\} $$

and

$$ \frac{G}{N} = g_1 N \cup \dots \cup g_p N= \cup ^{p}_{i=1} (g_p)^i N$$
    **lead 2**

$K \not \geq H $ so $[G:HN]<p$ and it divides $p$ so $$ \frac{|G|}{|HN|}=1$$ and the order of $|G|=|HN| $

that means that $HN=G$ since they have the same number of elements

---

**need $HN$ to be normal?? anything wrong/corrections??**

Comment: You appear to be assuming that $G$ is finite, but that isn't mentioned in the problem statement, nor is it required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that $HN$ is a subgroup because $N$ is normal, and $HN$ properly contains $N$. Now use the fact that
$$p = [G:N] = [G:HN][HN:N]$$
Since $[HN:N] > 1$ and $p$ is prime, this forces $[HN:N] = p$ and $[G:HN] = 1$. The latter equality implies that $G = HN$.